# kex_exchange_identification: read: Operation timed out

Tags: git, gitlab, ssh-keys

I am a developer at an Organization that uses Gitlab for version control. Everything was going fine when I got an error while pushing my commit.

```
kex_exchange_identification: read: Operation timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have tried every method I could to resolve it, for example generating a brand new ssh key and added into my account. I deleted the repo and tried to clone, but again I got the same error. Please help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

it could be because a restrict from gitlab in your area. you can use vpn for it.

Comment: Yeah perfect. You saved my life as I was trying it for 2 days. Cheers.